# Google drive api auth using service account

Tags: kotlin, google-drive-api

I'm trying to use Google drive with a Kotlin server app, no Android. Generated the admin service account with Google drive API enabled but can't upload a file,

```
401 Unauthorized
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?fields=id&uploadType=resumable
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
```

Same time I can log in with an O-Auth account, but it's not what I need.
My code:

```
fun uploadBasic(): String? {
    val credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(FileInputStream("gdrive-admin.json"))
    val requestInitializer: HttpRequestInitializer = HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials)

    // Build a new authorized API client service.
    val service = Drive.Builder(NetHttpTransport(), GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), requestInitializer)
        .setApplicationName("Drive samples").build()
    // Upload file photo.jpg on drive.
    val fileMetadata = File()
    fileMetadata.setName("img3.jpg")
    // Specify media type and file-path for file.
    val mediaContent = FileContent("image/jpeg", File("images/img3.jpg"))
    return try {
        val file = service.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent).setFields("id").execute()
        println("File ID: " + file.id)
        file.id
    } catch (e: GoogleJsonResponseException) {
        System.err.println("Unable to upload file: " + e.details)
        throw e
    }
}
```

Also I created a shared in Drive with the email of this service account but not sure how to use it.

UPD: This code works to show dirs but `GoogleCredential` is deprecated and also I'd like to use Kotlin Serialization:

```
    val httpTransport: HttpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport()
    val jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance()

    val credentialsFile = File("gdrive-admin.json")
    val credentials = GoogleCredential.fromStream(credentialsFile.inputStream(), httpTransport, jsonFactory)
        .createScoped(listOf("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"))

    val drive = Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credentials)
        .setApplicationName("Your Application Name")
        .build()

    val fileList: FileList = drive.files().list().execute()
    for (file in fileList.files) {
        println("File Name: ${file.name}")
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is the modern way to set credentials in Google Drive API:

```
    val httpTransport: HttpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport()
    val jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance()

    val credentialsFile = FileInputStream("gdrive-admin.json")
    val credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(credentialsFile).createScoped(listOf(DriveScopes.DRIVE))

    val requestInitializer: HttpRequestInitializer = HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials)

    val drive = Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, requestInitializer)
        .setApplicationName("Your Application Name")
        .build()
```